# 1 Comprehensive timer vs. multiple, a timer per object

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I got a question about good practice. I'm making a simple game and, I'm messing around with some sprites.

I have a sprite class. In that class there is a timer that runs every few milliseconds.

Now, I have a `List<Creatures>` and everyone of the "Creatures", got a Sprite object in them to run the animation. So that mean every creature has a timer that does the same thing.

I decided to change that, and make one timer that just iterate on the list, and call the function that create the animation for each "Creature".

What is a good practice?

1. Give every "Creature" its own timer.
2. Creating one "big" timer in the Form that iterate on the list, and call the function that is creating the animation from each object.
3. A different way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a sprite class. In that class there is a timer that runs every few milliseconds.

Unfortunately, it doesn't in reality. You are limited by the resolution of the (non-high performance) system clock, which is in the neighborhood of ~15 ms. So, you can set an interval of 1 if you like, but that's not what you actually get.

Back on topic, for a game, everything should run on the same clock. For each tick, you will have a loop which updates the logical state of the game (positions and whatnot) and then the display (animation frames, blit to screen, etc.).  You will likely run into problems if you have them on different timers as it will become extremely difficult to coordinate the state of your objects when they are being updated in parallel.

Also realize that you will need to normalize the update rate to ensure that things don't update too quickly or too slowly (depending on how long it takes for you to render a frame). You need to check the delta between the last update and the new update and act accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

If they all run at the same interval, one big timer is definitely the way to go.

Even if they run at different intervals, one big timer (with logic determining which sub-handlers fire) is often still the best.

Some libraries will add this logic internally, and only request a single timer from the OS.  You haven't said exactly which timer (.NET has at least four) you're using, so I'd recommend just using a centralized timer yourself.

Comment: im using System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Comment: @samy: Realize that this timer runs the `Tick` event delegate on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

You're best bet is going to be implementing a game loop that that keeps track of how much time has passed since the last loop iteration and then passes that elapsed time amount to all of the entities that need to update themselves.

For example, [OpenTk](http://www.opentk.com/) implements [several events](https://github.com/mono/opentk/blob/master/Source/OpenTK/GameWindow.cs) that occur on each pass through the game loop (e.g. OnUpdateFrame, OnRenderFrame).

Each of those events is passed an argument of type [FrameEventArgs](https://github.com/mono/opentk/blob/master/Source/OpenTK/FrameEventArgs.cs) which has a single property of Time:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a <see cref="System.Double"/> that indicates how many seconds of time elapsed since the previous event.
/// </summary>
public double Time 
{
    get { return elapsed; }
    internal set
    {
        if (value <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        elapsed = value;
    }
}
```

Based on the time elapsed, you can then figure out what animation frame to render in the sprite.

The added advantage is that by looking as this time elapsed you can figure out how many frames per second you're currently running at and make decisions based on it (skip the rendering of a frame, decrease render complexity, etc).